# sed not working in dockerfile but in container bash it does

Tags: bash, image, docker, sed, dockerfile

I'm creating a Docker image where I use sed to modify two parameters, but when i create the images and check the file I wanted to modify it remanis the same. If i run the very sed command interactively, i t works. Why? Could sombebody help me make ma image work without having to modify every container.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:slim-buster

WORKDIR /home/scr_dca

COPY . . 

ENV FLASK_APP Screenly.py

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt install curl gnupg -y && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev -y && \
    apt-get install libgssapi-krb5-2 g++ gcc && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt --trusted-host pypi.python.org 

RUN sed -i "s/\(MinProtocol *= *\).*/\1TLSv1.0 /" "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf" && \
    sed -i "s/\(CipherString *= *\).*/\1DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 /" "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf" 

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":8000", "scr_dca:app"]
```

I'm doing

```
docker run --name mycontainer -d -p 5050:8000 src_dca_v1.0 
docker container exec -it mycontainer bash
:/home/myapp#  cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

I checked and sed didnt work during the image creation so I ran the following commands:

```
sed -i "s/\(MinProtocol *= *\).*/\1TLSv1.0 /" "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf"
sed -i "s/\(CipherString *= *\).*/\1DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 /" "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf"
```

original part of the file I want to modify:

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = @SECLEVEL=1
```

sed expected result

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.0
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

Comment: You could try adding `cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` already in the Dockerfile after the two `sed` operations. Then we could see if the `sed` actually does work at this moment and something messes it up later.

Comment: Thanks for advice @bellackn, it was useful to debug and find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there is something you are not seeing or that you did not explain/describe in your question. As is, I cannot reproduce your problem.

My MCVE, inspired by your current question to test:

```
FROM python:slim-buster

RUN cp /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.ORI && \
    sed -i "s/\(MinProtocol *= *\).*/\1TLSv1.0 /" "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf" && \
    sed -i "s/\(CipherString *= *\).*/\1DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 /" "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf" && \
    (diff -u /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.ORI /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf || exit 0)
```

Note: I ignored diff exit status and force it to 0, as it will exit with status 1 when there is a difference between the files which would fail the build.

And the result:

```
$ docker build --no-cache -t test:test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/2 : FROM python:slim-buster
 ---> 3d8f801fc3db
Step 2/2 : RUN cp /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.ORI &&     sed -i "s/\(MinProtocol *= *\).*/\1TLSv1.0 /" "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf" &&     sed -i "s/\(CipherString *= *\).*/\1DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 /" "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf" &&     (diff -u /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.ORI /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf || exit 0)
 ---> Running in 523ddc0f4025
--- /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.ORI    2020-01-09 16:21:44.667348574 +0000
+++ /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf    2020-01-09 16:21:44.675348574 +0000
@@ -358,5 +358,5 @@
 system_default = system_default_sect

 [system_default_sect]
-MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
-CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
+MinProtocol = TLSv1.0 
+CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 
Removing intermediate container 523ddc0f4025
 ---> 88c28529ceb5
Successfully built 88c28529ceb5
Successfully tagged test:test
```

As you can see, `diff` is showing the differences before/after running sed and the modifications you are expecting are there.

We can also make sure those modifications persist when starting a container from this image:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name testcmd test:test bash -c "grep -A 2 '\[system_default_sect\]' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf"
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.0 
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

Comment: Yes, you were right, sed is actually working, it was a cheap mistake of mine that I was building image ..v1.1 when still running container from image v1.0. I lost all day trying to fix this. I replicated your code to confirm sed was indeed working when building the image, and it helped me a lot. Thanks you and sorry for this newbie mistake.